# PHP MyAdmin: how to enable table design view?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, designview

Am using `MySQL` `php MyAdmin` for database maintenace.My tables engine is `InnoDB`.My problem is that, I dont see table design view.I need to have design view for creating relations and DB structure view.I tried to insert `create_tables.sql` into my database, now I have some `pma_..` tables in my DB, but still no design view.What are the steps, for installing design view?

When I click Structure and relation view, here is what I see:

[image]

Still no design view

Comment: structure -> relation ? Or the designer tab?

Comment: which operating system are you using ?

Comment: Windows 8.1 operating system

Comment: download and install SQLyog from https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog

Answer (score 0):

try this

1. download and install `SQLyog` from [webyog.com/product/sqlyog](http://webyog.com/product/sqlyog)
2. run SQLyog, connect to MySQL host from `file->new connection`
3. Select your database
4. click on `file->new schema designer`, schema designer window will open.
5. drag and drop tables to schema designer window to design view

you will get the view like following

[image]

Comment: Where can I find mysqlHost adress? localhost is unsuitable.

Comment: use 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'

Comment: Also if you could mark this as answered that'd be helpful to me and to other SO users

Comment: But there is a small issue  'localhost or '127.0.0.1 dont allow me to connect.it says bad mysql host address.Where can I check my address?

Comment: ho do you accessing phpmyadmin in browser ? its like localhost/phpmyadmin ?

Comment: am using this: https://karosas.serveriai.lt/MyAdmin/ .So i must also use it in SQLyog?

Comment: yes, this will your host. if you want to access server's database in SQLyog you have to `Add Access Host` from cpanel. process:login to cpanel->click on "Remote MySQL" ->add "%" in textbox ->click on "Add Host" button. now try in SQLyog